# jquery ui helpers for mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

Are there helpers for jquery ui?

```
@Html.DatePicker(m=>m.Date)
```

or

```
@JQueryUI.DatePicker('DateFieldId');
```

I think it can be more conveniently...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add custom attributes/classes to your standard Html controls and then write Jquery selectors to wire them up:

Build this HTML (you could write a helper method extension to do this):

```
<input class="ui-datepicker" data-min="1/1/2000" type="text" />
```

Then in your javascript:

```
            (function($) {

                $(".ui-datepicker").datepicker({
                     minDate: Date.parse($(this).attr("data-min"))
                });

            })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 3):

No, are not any builtin Jquery UI helpers in framework. But there're many blog posts about implementation of datepicker (on of the most needed widgets, indeed). Take a look at [Stuart Leek's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2011/01/25/asp-net-mvc-3-integrating-with-the-jquery-ui-date-picker-and-adding-a-jquery-validate-date-range-validator.aspx) for example

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but for anyone looking for the answer to this question:

Try this:
http://jqueryuihelpers.apphb.com/Docmo/GettingStarted

I've been using it for quite some time now.. very, very nice